# I'm refactoring my code more clean and reusable. However after I refactored the code, one of the functions/features doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

###### Hey guys, I'm refactoring my code more clean and **reusable**. Here's what I would like to make.

- When you visit 'login' page, login.mp3 plays automatically on the page. ("plz enter your phone number~~")
- if there's any click event/action on the screen, the music stops playing.
- When you move to 'payment' page, payment.mp3 file plays automatically.
- if there's any click event/action on the screen, the music stops playing.

###### I hope you guys could understand what I'm trying to make

However after I refactored the code, 'stop playing music' feature doesn't work. It's supposed to work when I make click event on window. Can you guys help me how I can fix it? Thanks

##### Before Refactored

```
const LoginPhone = () => {
    const domNavigate = useDomNavigate();
    const {openKioskAlert} = useContext(KioskAlertContext);
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState([]);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);
    const audioFile = new Audio(`/sounds/hello.mp3`);

    // play audio sound
    const playSound = () => {
        audioFile.play();
    };

    // stop audio sound
    const stopSound = () => {
        audioFile.pause();
        audioFile.currentTime = 0;
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        playSound();
// when there's click event on window, it stops playing the music
        const clickHandler = () => stopSound();
        window.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    }, []);
```

##### After Refactored

###### loginPhone.tsx

```
import {voiceAudio} from '../../src/common/utils/voice';

const LoginPhone = () => {
    const domNavigate = useDomNavigate();
    const {openKioskAlert} = useContext(KioskAlertContext);
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState([]);
    const {playAudio, stopAudio} = voiceAudio('login-phone');

    useEffect(() => {
        playAudio();
        return () => stopAudio();
    }, []);
```

###### utils > voice.ts

```
export const voiceAudio = (title: string) => {
    const audioFile = new Audio(`/sounds/${title}.mp3`);
    const playAudio = () => audioFile.play();
    const stopAudio = () => {
        audioFile.pause();
        audioFile.currentTime = 0;
    };
    return {
        playAudio,
        stopAudio,
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are losing a reference to the old audio after assigning a new one.
First pause, then assign new sound

Comment: Hello Konrad! It's nice to see your feedback again. Thank you so much for your help! I tried your feedback(below), unfortunately it didn't work due to a block scope matter.
 So I created a new method to resolve the issue (you can see the code above.. I edited my code again), but I got the same issue. Can you advise me how I could go through it? Thank you :)

```
    audioFile.pause();
    audioFile.currentTime = 0;
    const audioFile = new Audio(`/sounds/${title}.mp3`);
```

Comment: Now you create a new audio each time you run this functions. It's like if you bought a music player, started playing a song and then instead of pausing, you buy another one and pause that new one that isn't even playing

Comment: Hello Konrad! The issue has been resolved by using Closure~!( the code has been modified so you can check.) One of the guys has suggested me using closure and it works! But I need to study about that some more.  :)